# Silex, class not found

Tags: php, class, controller, composer-php, silex

I want access of a function in my controller "ItemController". I always have the error; 
Fatal error: Class 'Iso\Controller\ItemController' not found ...

testsilex / Silex

```
 - app
 - composer.json
 - src
        - routes.php
        - Iso
            - Controller
                  - ItemController.php

 - vendor
 - web
       - index.php
```

I have an index.php file in Silex/Web

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require __DIR__.'/../app/app.php';
require __DIR__.'/../src/routes.php';
$app['debug'] = true;
$app->run();
```

My itemcontroller looks like:

```
<?php
namespace Iso\Controller;
use Silex\Application;
class ItemController
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request, Application $app)
    {
           echo "it works";
    }
}
```

My routes.php looks like:

```
$app->mount('/testsilex/silex/test', new Iso\Controller\ItemController());
```

My composer.json i added next line:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"Iso": "src/"}
    }
```

Does anyone know why my class is not found? It will be a small mistake but i can't find it. Thanks :)

Comment: Do you *dumpautoload* with composer?

Comment: I wonder if `"psr-0": {"Iso": "src/Iso"}` would be better...

Comment: I had the same problem and I had to run composer dumpautoload to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you need either an absolute identifer for your controller class. That is a leading backslash:

```
$app->mount('/testsilex/silex/test', new \Iso\Controller\ItemController());
```

Or you import the namespace with a `use` statement, which will always use full qualified names.

```
...
use Iso\Controller;
...
$app->mount('/testsilex/silex/test', new ItemController());
...
```

Answer (score 4):

In the composer config, namespaces are always specified with a trailing `\\`.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {"Iso\\": "src/"}
}
```

Check out the examples in the [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-0).